# How to encrypt stored procedure in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Could anyone get me syntax for encrypting the stored procedures in oracle.I am very new to this concept.Gone through Google, but didn't get much tips or syntax for it.
Thanks in Advance for the solutin

Comment: You can use either the 'wrap utility' or 'DBMS_DDL' subprogram based on your requirement. For the syntax , refer http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/wrap.htm#sthref3179

Comment: Please note,it takes only seconds to unwrap the code. You can paste the code online to a website and instantly get back the clear code

Answer (score 2):

To encrypt the Oracle procedures and functions you would use the WRAP binary. However, there is no official method to decrypt the procedures and functions. This is where source code control becomes necessary.

[Running the Wrap Utility|http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/wrap.htm#sthref3186]